# How to use $_GET variable from AJAX - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to use the $_GET variable into the blade.
The AJAX code work good, i received an alert with the correct value but i can't use it into the blade.

Route:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes per gestire la pagina "Home"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home', array('as' => 'success', 'uses' => 'StatisticheController@totaleRichiesteAnnue'));
```

home.blade.php

```
@if(isset($_GET['tipologia_evento_id']))
   <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('responsabile', 'Responsabile') !!}
   {!! Form::text('responsabile', old('_responsabile'), ['class' => 'form-control','disabled'=>'disabled']) !!}
   </div>
@endif
<script>
            var tipologia_evento_id = event.tipologia_evento_id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/home',
                data: { tipologia_evento_id: tipologia_evento_id},
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    alert(tipologia_evento_id);
                    $('#modal-event').modal('show');
                }
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 `request()` helper is available globaly

```
@if(request()->tipologia_evento_id)
 <div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('responsabile', 'Responsabile') !!}
 {!! Form::text('responsabile', old('_responsabile'), ['class' => 'form-control','disabled'=>'disabled']) !!}
 </div>
@endif
```

`request()->tipologia_evento_id` is not set it will return `null`

Hope this helps

Comment: levaral i don't unterstand how can i resolve the setting of request()->tipologia_evento_id because actually i got a NULL variable.

Comment: @CarmineRub because it returns null if it doesnot exist

Comment: In alert i got the correct value (alert(tipologia_evento_id);).
This means that it exists. This is why I do not understand why I receive a null value.

Comment: request()->tipologia_evento_id will not return null if it exist in your url like  `example.com?tipologia_evento_id=yourvalue` make sure it exist in your url

Comment: levaral i don't see nothing in url. Actually is like this.
  url: '/home', how can i change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Request** facade:

`Request::get('tipologia_evento_id');`

More details on: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Comment: I receive the null variable, why?

Answer (score 0):

As you already have route and controller, why not pass it from controller and use it in view?

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $getData = $request->all();

        return view('home', compact('getData'));
    }
}
```

in your view you can easily access as $getData

So your home.blad.php will look something like this

```
@if($getData->tipologia_evento_id)
   <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('responsabile', 'Responsabile') !!}
   {!! Form::text('responsabile', old('_responsabile'), ['class' => 'form-control','disabled'=>'disabled']) !!}
   </div>
@endif
```

EDIT:
If you want to get json response using ajax

```
class HomeController extends Controller
    {

        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $getData = $request->all();

            return response()->json($getData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @CarmineRub i was writing return view('index', compact('getData')); i have updated it should be return view('home', compact('getData'));

Comment: no problem, but I have not resolved yet!
Can you show me the correct route please?
Ajax code do I have to change it?

Comment: @CarmineRub do you mean you want to get the response data in ajax?

Comment: I'm using fullCalendar, and it work with Ajax. I need to pass a variable to route and then in controller like your example.

Comment: @CarmineRub i think you are trying to get json response from ajax, in that case you can't use 'return view' it should be 'return response'. I have edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code:

```
@if(app('request')->input('tipologia_evento_id'))
 <div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('responsabile', 'Responsabile') !!}
 {!! Form::text('responsabile', old('_responsabile'), ['class' => 'form-control','disabled'=>'disabled']) !!}
 </div>
@endif
```

OR

```
@if(Request::get('tipologia_evento_id'))
 <div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('responsabile', 'Responsabile') !!}
 {!! Form::text('responsabile', old('_responsabile'), ['class' => 'form-control','disabled'=>'disabled']) !!}
 </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I receive the null variable, why? How can i check this?